# SSMA for Access: Establishing connection with the source database failed. External component has thrown an exception

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to migrate an Access database (.accdb 2007-2016 format) to SQL Server Express 2016 (installed locally) using SSMA for Access.   I have been using SSMA for Access for years and have been upgrading as new releases come out so now running 9.4.   It's been a few weeks since the last successful conversion done on 9.4 and now suddenly I am receiving the error message in the title.  Using the UI, I have connected to my SQL database, have run the convert and load, but the migrate step is what is failing with the error.

`[Error: Datamigrator] [25208/1] [2023-10-23 13:43:26]: Establishing connection with the source database failed. [Error: Datamigrator] [25208/1] [2023-10-23 13:43:26]: Exception: External component has thrown an exception. site: Void GetDataSource(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper ByRef) source: System.Data error code: -2147467259 at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.DbUtilities.SsmaDbConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Access.Generic.AccessConnectionUtilities.ConnectToMdbFile(XNode xMdbFile, IUIAskPasswordProvider askPasswordProvider, IUIWorkgroupPolicyProvider workgroupPolicyProvider)
at Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Access.SqlServer.DataMigration.TableDataMigrator.ProcessNode(IDataMigrationContext context, A2SSDataMigrationState state, XNode node)`

I'm running this on Windows 11.

I removed the problem database and loaded one that I converted a few weeks ago and am now having the same trouble.  So it doesn't appear to be the Access database.
I'm not sure if it could be related to the .Net Framework version or not, as I'm trying to remember what may have changed.  I may have installed .Net Framework SDK 4.8 between last success and now, but not sure.   I can't figure out what is different and how I can connect to both source and destination to do the convert and load but can't complete the migrate.   I have uninstalled SSMA and rebooted multiple times.  Even went back to an older version of SSMA that worked and am having the same problem with it now.   So seems some component related to OLEDB is hosed.  Any Help?

I have also tried running the conversion through console mode and getting the same failure.

Comment: Did you try searching for the error code `-2147467259`? e.g.: _-2147467259 Error ODBC Microsoft Access Driver: The database has been placed in a state by an unknown user that prevents it from being opened or locked._ Do you have the .mdb file open in another application when you're trying to import its data?

Comment: Oh My!   Thank you for helping me to see what should have been obvious.  I did not have it open as far as I could tell, and could open the database multiple times by different instances of Access, but I saved the database to a new .accdb and that resolved the problem.   Would have thought my reboots would have freed some errant lock, but maybe I was recapturing it!   Thanks ever so much for the direction.